# How to assign a default (empty) value to the reference of a std::unordered_map in the declaration of a function?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a question, I've been doing some googling but I can't find a solution (yet).

I have a function that may / or may not receive a value of type **`std::unordered_map`**, as I indicate, on some occasions this **`std::unordered_map`** will be received empty and no processing of any kind will be executed on it, to achieve this, I assigned a value by default in declaration, like this:

```
bool existence_checker(const std::string&, std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> = {});
```

Declaring the function as indicated does not present any errors, since as far as I know (and would like opinions), a **`std::unordered_map`** can be assigned as empty in the same way as a **`std::vector`**.

The problem arises when I want to assign a default value to the reference of the **`std::unordered_map`**, I have done some tests with some answers found in google, but have not been successful. Something like this:

```
bool existence_checker(const std::string&, std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string>& = {});
```

**The error it throws is:**
error: could not convert ' ()' from '' to 'std :: unordered_map <std :: __ cxx11 :: basic_string , std :: __ cxx11 :: basic_string > & '|

**In short:** How can I assign a default (empty) value to the reference of a **`std::unordered_map`** in a function declaration?

*PD. Thanks in advance and sorry for the bad English.*

Comment: Does `const std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string>& = {}` not work?

Comment: @NathanOliver, I just updated the answer with the error: could not convert '<brace-enclosed initializer list> ()' from '<brace-enclosed initializer list>' to 'std :: unordered_map <std :: __ cxx11 :: basic_string <char >, std :: __ cxx11 :: basic_string <char>> & '|.

Comment: Why aren't you using `const` like you do for the first parameter?

Comment: maybe this ? `bool existence_checker(const std::string& = "", const std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> & = std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string>())`

Comment: @NathanOliver It happens that the `std::unordered_map` will be modified in the function, because of that I do not assign `const` to it. According to what I have read const should be added when the value will be read only. I'm starting with C++, I don't know if I'm misapplying the concepts.

Comment: @MuhammetAliAsan I will definitely try that. Thank you.

Comment: @JulioZaravia So the API design of your free function takes a non-const reference that _may_ or _may not_ be _modified_, and a user should be able to leverage a default argument for the _possibly modified_ in-out parameter? This sounds like an confusing API, and you may want to consider either overloading the function for the cases of "I need an unordered map and will modify it" and "I don't need a map and will not modify it" or wrapping the map object in a custom type where this API is a non-static member function (that may or may not modify the unordered map non-static data member).

Comment: ... otherwise we would go into the arguable C-style function API design, basically passing a pointer an unordered map, where the pointer may be `std::nullptr`, and where the default argument for the pointer parameter is set to `std::nullptr`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have a function that may / or may not receive a value of type `std::unordered_map` [...]

As your function *may* or *may not* receive an argument for a given parameter, you may want to consider changing the interface of the function to take a `std::optional` second parameter, which wraps you `std::unordered_map` type.

```
#include <optional>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

using MyUMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
bool existence_checker(const std::string& s = "", 
                       const std::optional<MyUMap>& um = std::nullopt);
```

Note that the particular problem in your example is that the second parameter is that of a non-const reference, an rvalue objects *cannot bind to non-const lvalue references*. I.e., if you want to provide a default argument for the second parameter, you will need<sup>(*)</sup> to make that parameter `const&`.

```
using MyUMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
bool existence_checker(const std::string& s = "", 
                       const MyUMap& um = {});
```

---

From the comments to the original posts, it is apparent that the API design of the free function is intended to a non-const reference that *may* or *may not* be *modified*, and a user should be able to leverage a default argument for the *possibly modified* in-out parameter. This looks very much like a C-style function API, and could be realized by passing a pointer an `std::unordered_map` object, where the pointer may be `std::nullptr`, and where the default argument for the pointer parameter is set to `std::nullptr`.

Instead of C-style API:s, you may want to consider either overloading the function for the cases of

> I need an unordered map and will modify it

and

> I don't need a map and will not modify it

or, wrapping the `std::unordered_map` object in a custom type where `existence_checker` API is a non-static member function (that may or may not modify the `std::unordered_map` non-static data member).

---

<sub>(*) You *could* use a default argument for a non-const reference parameter, but you would need to refer to an object of static storage duration, and this would be quite a weird pattern, and likely not what you were intending:</sub>

```
using MyUMap = std::unordered_map<std::string, std::string>;
MyUMap default_map_object_with_static_storage_duration{};

bool existence_checker(const std::string& s = "", 
                       MyUMap& um = default_map_object_with_static_storage_duration);
```

Comment: That is interesting, and very useful, applying `std::optional` to `std::unordered_map`, would it work the same as assigning `= ""` to `std::string`? I mean, can I send for example `object.existence_checker(string_var)`, and ignore the variable of type `std::unordered_map`? ... well, I'll give it a try. Thank you.

Comment: @JulioZaravia Yes, if you only send an explicit argument for the first (`const std::string&`) parameter, then the second (`const std::optional<MyUMap>&`) parameter will make use of the default argument for the call, which in this case is [`std::nullopt`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/optional/nullopt), indicating that the optional wraps "no value" (as compared to "some value").

Answer (score 0):

> How can I assign a default (empty) value to the reference of a std::unordered_map in a function declaration?

Write an overload that has a local empty map. Otherwise you might mutate that call site's default, then in later calls it isn't empty.

```
bool existence_checker(const std::string& str = "")
{
    std::unordered_map<std::string,std::string> empty;
    return existence_checker(str, empty);
}
```